# Diagnosing a freezing system, or renderer

Tags: fedora, graphics, opengl

Some quick background, I am running Fedora 19 x86_64 on a Dell Latitude with a 2nd gen i7 and discrete nvidia graphics card.

I have some rather obnoxious problems where the screen doesn't seem to render consistently. The freezes are irregular and short, but frequent. The system has behaved like that since install, and initially I noticed it in a certain online multiplayer 3D Java game. I thought it was lag, but single player and other games behave similarly. Then I realized it actually consistently happens in the Desktop Environment (Gnome 3) and at times is almost unusable. I had to wait for about 30 seconds typing a sentence in this question.

So what do I do to diagnose this problem? Who is most likely at fault? X? OpenGL? Graphics driver? Gnome 3? Kernel? Hardware?

I am not even sure how to check what driver is being used or whether the discrete card is being taken advantage of. Also, the cursor retains the ability to move during the freezes which even further confuses me. Why might I be able to wiggle the cursor, but nothing else (like text) will render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I answered my own question after slightly more work. I had been annoyed by this problem for some time and just never made the right connection.

NVIDIA Optimus. After installing lshw and running it with the video option, I noticed two displays active. One was for the i7, the other for the NVS 4200M. Did not take long to learn about Optimus, and after disabling Optimus in the BIOS everything ran smoothly.

Though I also swapped out nouveau for the proprietary driver as nouveau was rather slow.

My battery life has consequently also increased, and average temperature has decreased. Additionally, I found [a way to support Optimus.](http://bumblebee-project.org/) Perhaps the machines battery life and average temperature will improve again with that, as it was meant to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with graphics cards issues you have to take into account: kernel, the kernel module, xserver, xserver driver, mesa implementation, and a bunch of things, but that's what in the top of my head.

So, *how to diagnostic?* You should check the logs files `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `~/.xsession-errors`, also you my want to include `lspci | grep VGA`, the module you are using for your video card `lsmod`, if your system is correctly using Hardware Acceleration `glxinfo | grep render`, also if it's Gnome 3 the version of Gnome `gnome-shell --version`.

From there on, someone might spot what's bad with your configuration, possible updates that could improve the performance or limitations inherent to the free/non-free drivers.

> So what do I do to diagnose this problem?

Collect the most quantity of information of your system.

> Who is most likely at fault? X? OpenGL? Graphics driver? Gnome 3? Kernel? Hardware?

Sometimes X, sometimes Gnome 3, sometimes the kernel, sometime you just have crappy hardware, or just a combination of all above. Without looking at it, you would never know.

(I had a system that won't use the shinny new Gnome3 shell, and after trashing my system for a week, I found out that a package put a configuration file that forced the system to use gnome-fallback. I uninstalled the package (Debian), and now I'm happy).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I checked out those logs out of curiosity, but I also did find the answer and posted it here.

Comment: @lakechfoma well, actually I answered your questions, and where useful to you :P.